# jQuery: Cannot properly bind custom event with the same name on window and element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to bind a custom event with the same name on both `$(window)` and `$('#slider')`. Then I want to make the window event to trigger the element event.

So, the workflow would be:

```
1. Bind element event to say `Hello world` f.e.
2. Bind window event to trigger element event
3. Trigger window event
```

And the result:

```
1. Window event is triggered
2. Element event is triggered
```

Everything looks good, but once the window event is triggered, the whole thing goes into a crazy self-calling loop, until the browser crashes.

It simply looks as if the element event triggers back the event on window.

Here's my code:

```
$('#slider').bind('asd', function() {
    console.log('asd called on slider');
});
$(window).bind('asd', function() {
    console.log('asd called on window');
    $('#slider').trigger('asd');
}).trigger('asd');
```

Comment: Events bubble. triggering an event on a child of the window will result in the event eventually reaching the window unless you stop propagation.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: assuming #slider is part of the window, then bubbling will accomplish this with a single binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events bubble. triggering an event on a child of the window will result in the event eventually reaching the window unless you stop propagation.

One way around this is to just trigger the handler, not the event.

```
$('#slider').bind('asd', function() {
    console.log('asd called on slider');
});
$(window).bind('asd', function() {
    console.log('asd called on window');
    $('#slider').triggerHandler('asd');
}).trigger('asd');
```

And here's another way:

```
$('#slider').bind('asd', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('asd called on slider');
});
$(window).bind('asd', function() {
    console.log('asd called on window');
    $('#slider').trigger('asd');
}).trigger('asd');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use event.stopPropagation() to stop DOM bubbling:

```
$('#slider').bind('asd', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log('asd called on slider');
});
$(window).bind('asd', function() {
    console.log('asd called on window');
    $('#slider').trigger('asd');
}).trigger('asd');
```